# 50% chance for two sets of two variables

Tags: javascript

I have two sets of two variables, and I was wondering how to add a 50% chance of them switching between the two.

Here are the **variables** im trying to use

[image]

How would I make it so it has a 50/50 chance of switching between the "cells switch order" code and the "cells DONT switch order code?" So that way it randomly selects which of the two sets of variables to use? Thank you

Comment: Put the two conditions on the either side of a test against Math.random() > 0.5

Answer (score 1):

You can use Math.random().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```
if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    //Cells switch order
}
else {
    //Cells don't switch order 
}
```